# java How to prevent user from using the same object which involves infinite loop?

Tags: java

I made a Linked List for practice which the insert function does this:

```
public void insert(Node node){
    if(this.head == null){
        this.tail = node;
    }

    node.next = this.head;
    this.head = node;
    this.length++;
}
```

the problem is that it will cause infinite loop if user insert the same object twice:

```
    Node node = new Node(10);
    list.insert(node);
    list.insert(node);
```

Do I have to check if the node instance exists in the list already or not?

Comment: Shouldn't they be inserting _values_ (that you then put into Nodes)? If you let them insert nodes, they have free control to mess up your list.

Comment: Nodes shouldn't be exposed to the user, they should be an internal feature of your list.  The nodes themselves should be inaccessible to the user. If a user enters two values twice the list should create two nodes; each containing the same reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't test below code but it may solve your problem:

```
public void insert(Node node)
{
    if(this.head == null) {
        this.head = node;
        this.tail = node;
    }
    else {
        this.tail.next = node;
        this.tail = this.tail.next;
    }

    this.length++;
}
```

By the way as @Brandon Ibbotson and @flakes suggested, hide operations with Node from the user.